# Is there any requirement for a USB cable to be qualified enough for single-lane 10Gbps singaling?

Tags: usb, cable

Assuming a host (including its ports and whatsoever) and a device both supports USB 3.1 Gen 2 / USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 (i.e. USB 3.2 Gen 1x2 is not considered), does a user need a "good enough" (e.g. short enough, made with "enough" copper) cable for the 10Gbps signal rate?

More specifically, could a cable that is "practically good enough" for 5Gbps signal rate not good enough for a 10Gbps connection?

If 10Gbps cable "is a thing", is it possible for an OS to "programmatically" detect / identify whether the cable is indeed capable of 10Gbps signaling? (By programmatically I mean like not via any benchmark-like method.) (AFAIK, the Gen2 standards does not involve anything like the E-Marker that exists in some USB-C cables.)

And if not, could a not-good-enough-for-Gen2 cable be "overloaded" and lead to packet loss or anything like that?

(I suppose amperage that the cable can "support" could matter in practice, but let's focus on data link / capability identification in this question.)

Comment: @Ramhound Not really. I mean AFAIK, they are not significantly different. (I am aware that semantically speaking, USB 3.1 and USB 3.2 are different versions of standards, and I am sure there are "details" that have been changed, if that's what you meant, but otherwise, no, I am not aware that they are "not the same thing". At the very least, both uses 128b/132b encoding according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0).) Either way, that is not the focus of my question either. Let's say both the device and the host *are either both* `USB 3.1 Gen 2` *or* `USB 3.2 Gen 2x1`.

Comment: @Ramhound seriously what's your point here? You first imply that they "are not the same thing", then you said they "are identical", let alone the fact that 3 **.2** is literally an indication of  the fact that *specification-wise* it's a new version (or "revision") that supersedes 3.1 (and in turn 3.0). So far you haven't pointed out whether any of these is relevant to my question (e.g. whether the 3.2 specs introduces some mechanism that addresses exactly my doubt). So can we just end this text game regarding versioning here now?

Comment: @Ramhound just to save us sometime: in case you thought / what you meant was that `USB 3.2 Gen 2x1` is not the same thing as `USB 3.2 Gen 2`, then you can cut it, because they are. The only things (regarding 10Gbps) that are different are 2x1 vs 1x2 (aka dual-lane gen 1), and I've said already the case of 1x2 is not my concern here (because obviously you need a proper C cable for 2 lanes).